# Create list with a large number of elements

Tags: r, performance, list

I need to create a list with 10^5 elements.
This is my code:

```
gamma1 <- 2.2
C1 <- zeta(x = gamma1)
C1inverse <- 1/C1 

listN <- c((10^3), (10^4), (10^5))

for(N in listN) {
  listKseq <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0) 

  for(k in 1:N) { 
    ki <- N * C1inverse * k^(-gamma1)
    listKseq <- c(listKseq, ki) 
  }

  print(paste("I created list with N = ", length(listKseq), " nodes.", sep = ""))
}
```

This code works for N=10^3 and N=10^4 but not for N=10^5.
In fact the result of the `print` is:

```
[1] "I created list with N = 1000 nodes."
[1] "I created list with N = 10000 nodes."
```

Really no errors are generated, but the execution takes too long and after a while I stop (15 min are not enough).

Is there a faster way to generate lists like that?

Thanks

Comment: In your example you used a function call zeta(). This isn't in the base R package. If it is important (e.g. returns a non-scalar result) you should specify where it comes from. If it does just return a simple number you should edit it out.

Comment: Yeah, my google-based guess is library(VGAM)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a 'copy-and-append' strategy where you allocate a zero-length list and then grow it with each iteration

```
listKseq <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0)
...
    listKseq <- c(listKseq, ki)
```

Instead, 'pre-allocate and fill'

```
listKseq <- vector(mode = "list", length = N)
...
    listKseq[[k]] = ki
```

The 'copy-and-append' strategy makes a copy of all the data already calculated, each time through the loop, so it has polynomial complexity (scales as `N * (N - 1) / 2`, which is approximately `N^2`). The pre-allocate and fill does not cause a copy, and scales linearly with `N`.

Here's the original and modified implementations

```
f0 <- function(N) {
    gamma1 <- 2.2
    C1 <- zeta(x = gamma1)
    C1inverse <- 1/C1 
    listKseq <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0)
    for(k in 1:N) { 
        ki <- N * C1inverse * k^(-gamma1)
        listKseq <- c(listKseq, ki)
    }
    listKseq
}

f1 <- function(N) {
    gamma1 <- 2.2
    C1 <- zeta(x = gamma1)
    C1inverse <- 1/C1 
    listKseq <- vector(mode = "list", length = N)
    for(k in 1:N) { 
        ki <- N * C1inverse * k^(-gamma1)
        listKseq[[k]] <- ki
    }
    listKseq
}
```

A demonstration that they return the same result

```
> identical(f0(1000), f1(1000))
[1] TRUE
```

and that they scale as described

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f0(1000), f0(10000), f1(1000), f1(10000), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr        min         lq        mean     median          uq         max
  f0(1000)   9.017734   9.128453    9.779840   9.242001    9.275092   14.975256
 f0(10000) 954.733153 965.318717 1002.789735 969.329023 1002.291013 1125.090369
  f1(1000)   2.332049   2.417364    2.462379   2.461930    2.488568    2.583112
 f1(10000)  22.220757  22.393636   22.725043  22.503726   22.797767   24.376800
 neval cld
    10  a 
    10   b
    10  a 
    10  a
```

In `f1()`, the burden to pre-allocate and fill fall to the person writing the code. Use `lapply()` to get this behavior for free with more expressive, compact, and robust code

```
f1a <- function(N) {
    gamma1 <- 2.2
    C1 <- zeta(x = gamma1)
    C1inverse <- 1/C1 
    lapply(seq_len(N), function(k) N * C1inverse * k^(gamma1))
}
```

Further, your calculation can be 'vectorized' instead of written as a loop

```
f2 <- function(N) {
    gamma1 <- 2.2
    C1 <- zeta(x = gamma1)
    C1inverse <- 1/C1 
    as.list(N * C1inverse * seq_len(N) ^ (-gamma1))
}
```

...and it doesn't make sense to return a list-of-length-1 elements, when a simple vector would do

```
f3 <- function(N) {
    gamma1 <- 2.2
    C1 <- zeta(x = gamma1)
    C1inverse <- 1/C1 
    N * C1inverse * seq_len(N) ^ (-gamma1)
}
```

Identity and times are

```
> identical(unlist(f1(1000)), f3(1000))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(f1(10000), f2(10000), f3(10000), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
      expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
 f1(10000) 22330.886 22482.578 24223.9281 22939.443 24100.424 30414.666    10
 f2(10000)  1196.715  1217.937  1256.7939  1242.236  1256.622  1401.922    10
 f3(10000)   887.824   909.951   981.8528   979.900   996.471  1201.596    10
 cld
   b
  a 
  a
```

It's neat to see how these improvements help -- the scaling of the algorithm is most important for large data, then the use of vectorization, and finally appropriate representation. At some point one would perhaps stop thinking about the code, because it was 'good enough'.

It's clear that copy-and-append is a very bad strategy, so in the case of unknown length over-allocate and trim to size `res = vector("list", 1e7); ...; length(res) = actual_length`, or allocate in big chunks so that you copy-and-append, but only a few times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply so fast and precise. And if I don't know a priori the final length? Obviously is not the case of the example (which I simplified).